# How to format JSON into a single javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a **JSON**  string in the following format.

```
{
"dt_total_score": [
{
  "score": 60.8332,
  "gText": "Total"
},
{
  "score": 66.6666,
  "gText": "Call Center"
},
{
  "score": 66.6666,
  "gText": "Restaurant reservation"
},
{
  "score": 50,
  "gText": "Arriving (Trams) - Experience or Observation"
},
{
  "score": 60,
  "gText": "Arrival & Parking Experience"
}
],
"dt_trend": [
{
  "score": 60,
  "gText": "Q1,2018",
  "seriesName": "Arrival & Parking Experience",
  "ONUM": 1
},
{
  "score": 50,
  "gText": "Q1,2018",
  "seriesName": "Arriving (Trams) - Experience or Observation",
  "ONUM": 1
},
{
  "score": 66.6666,
  "gText": "Q1,2018",
  "seriesName": "Call Center",
  "ONUM": 1
},
{
  "score": 66.6666,
  "gText": "Q1,2018",
  "seriesName": "Restaurant reservation",
  "ONUM": 1
},
{
  "score": 60.8333,
  "gText": "Q1,2018",
  "seriesName": "Total",
  "ONUM": 2
},
{
  "score": 60.8333,
  "gText": "Q4,2017",
  "seriesName": "Total",
  "ONUM": 2
},
{
  "score": 60.8333,
  "gText": "Q3,2017",
  "seriesName": "Total",
  "ONUM": 2
}
]
,
"dt_compartive":[  
  {  
     "gText":"Total",
     "percentDiff":6083.0000
  }
 ]
  }
```

In the above JSON :

1. dt_total_score has instantaneous score of a particular category.
2. dt_trend has trend of score for a given time frame(Quarters in the above case but can be week or Months too).
3. dt_comparative has the percentage difference in the scores in the time frame

I have to parse and merge the above data on the basis of categories into a list of Javascript object in the following manner.
**Please note that this data is just for explaining how I want the output and not related to the above data**

```
var dt_score_n_trend = [

{
gText:"Call Center",
score: 60.2223,
trendName:[ "Q1,2018", "Q2,2018"],
trendValue:[ 60, 70],
PercentageDiff:70
},
 {
gText:"Call Center",
score: 60.2223,
trendName: [ "Q1,2018", "Q2,2018"],
trendValue:[ 60, 70],
PercentageDiff:70
}
];
```

So far I have unsuccesfully tried to parse the JSON into a Javascript object and then trying to merge them.

How do I merge them into above manner ?

**edit:Updated the question and removed errors in formatting**

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really help us to figure out the issue with your code. For further information, please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: this `{{},{},{}}` is not possible. you have to use some thing like this `[{},{},{}] ` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

Comment: `Total` has `Q1`, `Q3` and `Q4`, but in your output it only has `Q1` and `Q2`. Please explain how you reach this output.

Comment: Can you please tell me the criteria you used to create the resuted JSON?

Comment: json1.concat(json2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group `dt_trend` array based on `seriesName`. Create an accumulator object and for each new `seriesName` add a new object and for the old one update the trend value. Then extract out all the values.

```js
var data = { "dt_total_score": [ { "score": 60.8332, "gText": "Total" }, { "score": 66.6666, "gText": "Call Center" }, { "score": 66.6666, "gText": "Restaurant reservation" }, { "score": 50, "gText": "Arriving (Trams) - Experience or Observation" }, { "score": 60, "gText": "Arrival & Parking Experience" } ], "dt_trend": [ { "score": 60, "gText": "Q1,2018", "seriesName": "Arrival & Parking Experience", "ONUM": 1 }, { "score": 50, "gText": "Q1,2018", "seriesName": "Arriving (Trams) - Experience or Observation", "ONUM": 1 }, { "score": 66.6666, "gText": "Q1,2018", "seriesName": "Call Center", "ONUM": 1 }, { "score": 66.6666, "gText": "Q1,2018", "seriesName": "Restaurant reservation", "ONUM": 1 }, { "score": 60.8333, "gText": "Q1,2018", "seriesName": "Total", "ONUM": 2 }, { "score": 60.8333, "gText": "Q4,2017", "seriesName": "Total", "ONUM": 2 }, { "score": 60.8333, "gText": "Q3,2017", "seriesName": "Total", "ONUM": 2 } ], "dt_compartive":[{"gText":"Total","percentDiff":6083.0000}]},
    result = data.dt_trend.reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.seriesName] = r[o.seriesName] || {gText: o.seriesName, score: o.score, trendName: [], trendValue: []};
      r[o.seriesName].trendName.push(o.gText);
      r[o.seriesName].trendValue.push(o.score);
      return r;
    },{});
data.dt_compartive.forEach(o => {
  result[o.gText].PercentageDiff = o.percentDiff;
});
var output = Object.values(result);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .
Can you tell me what to do if i have another field called dt_comparative in the above data and I have to join that to the final result wrt to category

Comment: You have to iterate the dt_comparative and add the property by first finding the object in the result and then adding the required property.

Comment: I have updated the question based on new requirements.
I appreciate your effort to help.
Can you change you answer based on new requirements ?

Comment: Updated my solution. The new solution will populate `PercentageDiff ` to  object whose `gText` value exists in the `dt_compartive` array, other object will remain unaffected.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
That really helped.!